# GNOME Display Manager says "OK" but does not launch

Tags: gnome, 15.10

I recently tried to install the GNOME desktop environment on my Ubuntu 15.10. The installation took a while and then prompted me to restart the computer. That's what I did but when relaunching, it indefinitely only shows a black screen saying :

```
fsck from util-linux 2.26.2
/dev/sda5: clean, */* files, */* blocks
[ OK ] Created slice user-120.slices
       Starting User Manager for UID 120...
[ OK ] Started Session c1 of user gdm.
[ OK ] Started User Manager for UID 120.
       Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
[ OK ] Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
       Stopping User Manager for UID 120...
[ OK ] Started Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
       Starting GNOME Display Manager...
[ OK ] Started GNOME Display Manager.
_
```

... and that's all.

I can still access the terminal and log in using <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + F2</kbd>

I probably made a mess during the installation (I forget to add the `-shell` when typing `sudo apt-get install gnome`) and hope it's not too serious.

I apologize for my bad English and if a similar question was already answered.

Answer (score 0):

I am also experiencing this problem, and so far no fixes can be found. Unlike yours, I cannot access terminal.

Since you can use terminal, try this command:

```
sudo gdm
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Due to customization many thing won't opens in Ubuntu

```
dconf reset -f /
```